# <a> tags not working for cordova app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am making a Cordova app that has buttons that are supposed to launch a link to the external browser. I However when I build the app for Android or use the app to connect to my hosted project, links don't work. When I try clicking on a button or a tag I don't see my animation and nothing happens but it workes fine on my PC's browser. I tried looking this up and found that changes to the config file or new plugins can cause these tags do not work but my config.xml looks like it's supposed to and I reinstalled/downgraded the inappbrowser plugin to a version that I have used on older working projects. How can I figure out what I'm doing wrong?

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.example.bookapp" version="1.0.0">
  <name>book app</name>
  <description>
        app
    </description>
  <author email="email" href="website">
        author
    </author>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"/>
  </platform>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="^0.9.0-beta.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2"/>
  <engine name="android" spec="~7.0.0"/>
  <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.3"/>
  <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4"/>
</widget>
```

My html document with the broken links:

```
 <main>
  <section class="dynamic-card">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a class="contact-link website waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#">
      <span class="network-name">
       email
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="contact-link email waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#" onclick="website()">
      <span class="network-name">
       website
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="contact-link waves-effect waves-light btn facebook" href="#" onclick="facebook()">
      <span class="network-name">
       Facebook
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="contact-link twitter waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#" onclick="twitter()">
      <span class="network-name">
       Twitter
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="contact-link instagram waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#" onclick="instagram()">
      <span class="network-name">
       instagram
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </main>
```

like I said the links behave normally on Chrome but once I get it on my phone the links behave like buttons without a href attribute or a click/hover animation.

Comment: Do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html? if so, provide it in the question. Also provide the code of website(), facebook(), twitter() or instagram() functions as that's the important part

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` tags in cordova apps are not working properly, you have to use InAppBrowser, use JavaScript to call window.open with the target argument set to _system, as per the InAppBrowser documentation:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system');">Google</a>
```

This will work but for better practise, intercept all link and their click events and call window.open  method with argument as link read from href attribute.

To install InAppBrowser plugin execute following command. This is must do step in order to make this work.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```